# Memory usage in javaFx

Tags: java, javafx

I created a `ScrollPane` and it has a `StackPane` as a child with the size of 2000 in 2000 pixels now i fill my `StackPane` with some pieces of this image :

[image]

i add all images to my stackPane with this code

```
 ImageView grass = new ImageView(Url.GRASS);
        double x = grass.getImage().getWidth();
        double y = grass.getImage().getHeight();
        for(int i=0 ; i < 2000/x ;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<2000/y;j++){
                ImageView grassTemp = new ImageView(Url.GRASS);
                myStackPane.getChildren().add(grassTemp);
                grassTemp.setTranslateX(-2000/2+(x)*i);
                grassTemp.setTranslateY(-2000/2+(y)*j);

                grassTemp.setCache(true);
                grassTemp.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
            }
        }
```

Now i see it takes about 50- 60 MB (without `setCache` and `setCacheHint`) of my memory usage 
i used these functions to have a better performance

```
    myStackPane.setCache(true);
    myStackPane.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
```

And all images

```
 grassTemp.setCache(true);
 grassTemp.setCacheHint(CacheHint.SPEED);
```

But i see it only reduce about 4-6 MB of my memory usage

Now what is your opinion to have a better performance and better memory usage for loading lots of images ?
Thanks in advance

**Note**:i want to use these images to create a small map for my small game

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok.but which part is unclear ?

Comment: What `image` is, how many images you are creating, how you are using imageview, why there is a stack pane involved, why you are putting 117 images in a stack pane as they will just stack on top of each other and you will only see the top 1 image anyway, etc.

Comment: Edited. i create a stackpane because ,in fact i want to create a simple game which has a ground and some object that they are moving in my ground(this image in top using for create my ground) because of that i used stackpane and i add this stackpane to a scrollbar to simply scroll through the map

Answer (score 0):

All your image views are of the same image.  You don't need to load new image data, just to replicate the image.

Instead of:

```
ImageView grassTemp = new ImageView(Url.GRASS)
```

Do:

```
Image grassImage = new Image(Url.GRASS) // **outside the loops
. . .     
ImageView grassTemp = new ImageView(grassImage) // **inside the loops.
```

You should probably just use a standard Pane or Group and set layout values on the image views (or use a GridPane) rather than using a StackPane with translation.

Also, as an alternative, you could use a CSS background with repeat for this task.